# Running dotnet run command throws error Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system

Tags: 20.04, snap, dotnet

I was using .net core 3.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 for a while but now after a system update the skd does not seem to recognize the installed libicu. I am currently on dotnet 3.1.407.

```
dotnet run
```

Error Message:
Process terminated. **Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system**. Set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support.
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.GetGlobalizationInvariantMode()
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode..cctor()

I verified that this is installed.

```
ii  libicu66:amd64    66.1-2ubuntu2    amd64  International Components for Unicode
```

Interestingly and when running the Application Test directly it works -> dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Test.dll

There a some suggestions out there to set the the Globalization.Invariant to true,

```
    "configProperties": {
        "System.Globalization.Invariant": true }
```

which works but is not applicable to my situation as that prevents EntityFramework from connecting to the SQL Database -> Globalization.Invariant is not supported.

dotnet info output:

NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   3.1.407
Commit:    d3244d0e44

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     ubuntu
OS Version:  20.04
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
Base Path:   /snap/dotnet-sdk/117/sdk/3.1.407/

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.13
Commit:  64df28ec4a

.NET Core SDKs installed:
3.1.407 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/117/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/117/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/117/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Any tips to fix this are highly appreciated.

Comment: I am using JetBrains Rider to run my projects. After spending a few hours more on debugging this issue, I found that my projects still run using Visual Studio Code. Then I downgraded to an earlier version of Rider and and my programs still run there. So it may well be an issue with Rider and not Linux. I opened an inquiry with Rider and will update this post here when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

After all, it turns out to be a problem with the Snap installation of the .NET SDK. I uninstalled the snap package and installed .net 3.1 SDK binary directly as instructed on this page [microsoft .net installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual). Scroll down to the chapter "manual installation". Download the binary and install the SDK.
My programs builds and run fine again.